# When someone updates an android app does it count as new install?

Tags: android, google-play

I have published an app on Android Market. I recently updated it. I want to know if some user updates his app would it count as a new install in the reports?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it would not count as a new download. It is just an update. If you look in the new statistics report at market.android.com/publish, you can see the detailed reports of updates and installs.

Answer (score 0):

With the new stats as of last week it's all seperated out when you look at the details.  Not sure historicaly.